# How do I disable the default translation feature for a custom field?

Tags: plugin-development, craft3

I am making a custom field that provides granular control of what values will be translated and what values will remain shared across multiple sites.

Because of that, I'd prefer to entirely the disable the default translation feature of the field so users cannot accidentally set the field to be translatable (which would defeat its purpose).

Is this possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set the [translation method](https://github.com/craftcms/cms/blob/develop/src/base/Field.php#L89)  for each field individually

```
public static function supportedTranslationMethods(): array 
{ 
    return
    [ 
         self::TRANSLATION_METHOD_NONE 
    ];
 }
```